# Non square Matrix multiplication

Tags: matrices

Assuming we have the following matrix multiplication problem

$$ {\bf A x} = {\bf b}$$
and that the dimensions of ${\bf A,x,b}$ are the following $3\times2$, $2\times 1$ and $3\times 1$

How can one find solutions to such problem?

Any references or suggestions.is this the sparsity constrained problem?

Answer (score 3):

It is unusual to have the matrix of unknowns be not a column (or row) matrix.  Hence you should rewrite the problem to be $A'x'=b'$, where now $x'$ is an $8\times 1$ column vector, $A'$ is a $12\times 8$ sparse matrix, and $b'$ is a $12\times 1$ column vector.  The result can be handled using normal [Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination).

Comment: Thanks for comment, what does sparse matrix mean?

Comment: Sparse means lots of zeroes.  In this case $A'$ will have at most two nonzero entries in each row.